# Skill and Knowledge Based System

Tags: game-recommendation, skills, knowledge-check

I am planning a steampunk play-by-post game.  Although I started by homebrewing Pathfinder, I've found that the skills (and especially knowledge/profession) aren't robust enough to handle my needs.

I'm looking for a system that focuses on what a character *knows*, rather than their equipment, magical abilities, or tactical options.

The ideal system would include:

- A highly granular skill system, encompassing a very large number of specific skills. I anticipate requiring both technological skills and a variety of social skills
- Within the realm of knowledge, include options for specialization, perhaps in the form of academic research, personal interest, or career-knowledge
- Provide mechanics for revealing additional information to players based on successes (what counts as a success might vary from system to system)
- Some means of preventing a single player from dominating all skills. A single character shouldn't be a master of all technical disciplines, fields of knowledge, and careers.

Comment: This describes nearly every skill-based system (and [there are many](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1475/321)). What else do you want from such a system, besides the basic features common to skill-based systems?